# How to get the contents of the bootstrap nav tab to occupy only a single line?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Given this [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)

([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M7M3.png))

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display: inlne-block">
    <li class="nav-item" style="text-align: center;  display: inline;">
      <div>
        <a class="nav-link active show p-1" data-toggle="tab" href role="tab">1</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" style="margin-left: 7px;">Brick 1</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" style="text-align: center;  display: inline;">
      <a class="nav-link active show p-1" data-toggle="tab" href role="tab">2</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" style="margin-left: 7px;">Brick 2</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The `a` and `button` must appear in a single line. 
  I cannot put the `button` inside the `a` because each element has a separate event handler.

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298447/how-to-make-ul-list-items-in-a-single-line) using `display: inline` but that does not work.

Here the JSFiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/km7wat86/4/

Comment: i have fixed your code check it. https://jsfiddle.net/xLenwf81/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `d-flex` on the nav-item's to make them `display:flex`...

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tab">
     <li class="nav-item d-flex" style="text-align: center">
        <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href role="tab">1</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-pump-data" style="margin-left: 7px;">Pumpe 1</button>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item d-flex" style="text-align: center">
         <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href role="tab">2</a>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-pump-data" style="margin-left: 7px;">Pumpe 2</button>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/75sYRZ0Jyy)

Answer (score -1):

Give `float:left` to the `anchor tag`.

```css
a{
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item" style="text-align: center">
      <div>
        <a class="nav-link active show p-1" data-toggle="tab" href role="tab">1</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-pump-data" style="margin-left: 7px;">Pumpe 1</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link active show p-1" data-toggle="tab" href role="tab">2
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-pump-data" style="margin-left: 7px;">Pumpe 1</button></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: well design not proper

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand??